# Scrapy merge data from subpage

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm new on scrapy and I'm trying to parse a website to extract information.  I would like to create a single dictionary that contains info of page `A` and of all the subpages of `A`. To make it more concrete, think about the page of a basketball team and as the subpages the page of each player.

Now, I can parse the page of the `team` and I can parse the page of the `players`, the problem is how can I merge the dictionary?
(i'm not using items nor pipelines)

So far I've done a loop inside the main page that `yields` a request parse to the `player` url. I'm passing the main `dict` to the `player` parser (in the `request.meta`) that adds the `player_<i>` info (where `i` is a counter passed in the meta) to the team dictionary. The `player` parser returns the dictionary with the added information. The problem is that, in this way, the team is yield many times resulting in an inusable csv that conatins serverl rows of a dictionary containing some players and the team data (actually the first is 1 player, the second 2 players and so on).

How can I've just a single row with all the players' data and team data?

**edit**
The structure is somehow like this, (no there's no common data across team or players)

Team:

- name
- descriptio
- website
- league

Team:

- name
- age
- website

Comment: Do the players and the team have the same fields (keys) though? I suggest you post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or at least some code

Comment: edited. but there's no common structure among the two.

Comment: You need to (a) post the code you have so far and (b) post an example of what you want the output to look like, especially if there is no common structure